# Узнать позицию курсора относительно объекта UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Есть `UI` объект на странице, как я могу на событие `PointerEntered` определить координаты мыши относительно этого объекта? Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы отобразить курсор изменения размера в правильном положении. я вроде получаю координаты объекта и мыши, но когда, как я думаю, навожу мышь в 0:0 и мой объект там же, то координаты разные

Мой метод

```
 private void Border_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = sender as Border;
        var ct = (CompositeTransform)border.RenderTransform;
        var ttv = border.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
        var bordercoords = ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        var borderHeight = border.ActualHeight+ct.ScaleY;
        var borderWidth = border.ActualWidth+ct.ScaleX;
        var mouseAbsoluteCoords = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;


        if (bordercoords.Y -3>=mouseAbsoluteCoords.Y || mouseAbsoluteCoords.Y <= bordercoords.Y+3 && mouseAbsoluteCoords.X > bordercoords.X + 10 && mouseAbsoluteCoords.X < borderWidth - 10)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = bottomTopCursor;
        }
    }
```

Проверкой пытаюсь покрыть участок верхней границы, я себе представляю это так: когда курсор в синей зоне, активируется нужный курсор. Так же и для других областей

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте там, где обозначено синим, невидимый элемент, и на нем сделайте изменение курсора как нужно при наведении. Тогда ничего высчитывать не придется.

Comment: А если красная рамка это это ячейка Grid`a, то могу ли я создать вокруг нее еще ячейки и элемент немного сместить к центру?

Comment: Если это таблица, у которой надо менять размеры ячеек, то существует готовый контрол.

Comment: Нет, это картинка в Grid с кнопками в верхнем ряду и размер меняется не ячейки, а всего Grid

Comment: Я вас правильно понял?   http://joxi.ru/V2V5g9kIXkJjmv

Comment: Вроде бы да, но лучше убрать наложения.